# i want to use same query for fetch all record and specific id records in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i want to fetch all records if my catid is null and fetch specific id data if catid is provided using same query here is my code

```
 $catid=$_GET['cat'];
    if($_GET['cat'] = '' || $_GET['cat'] = null ){
        $sel="select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();  
    }else{
    $sel="select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and `category`='{$catid}' order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();
}

    $result=mysql_query($sel);


    $listProducts = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){

    $listProducts[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array

    };
```

Comment: Firstly, replace `if($_GET['cat'] = '' || $_GET['cat'] = null ){` with `if($_GET['cat'] == '' || $_GET['cat'] == null ){` . You have to use double `==` if you want to compare. Secondly, if you get no results after editing this line then update your question - there will be an error probably with the `sql` queries -  or connection . Thirdly, use `mysqli_*` because `mysql_` is deprecated and vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: avoid use of mysql_* function() because these are not deprecated in php 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please replace `=` with `==`

```
if($_GET['cat'] = '' || $_GET['cat'] == null ){
```

A better approach would be this:

```
if (isset($_GET['cat']) && !empty($_GET['cat'])) {
```

Comment: `empty` is enough as it returns true if the key is not defined. " A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. "

Answer (score 1):

> try below one:

```
<?php
    $sel = !empty($_GET['cat']) ? "select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and `category`='{$catid}' order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql() : "select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();

    $result=mysql_query($sel);

    $listProducts = array(); // create a variable to hold the information
    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) !== false){

        $listProducts[] = $row; // add the row in to the results (data) array

    };
```

Comment: Good use of ternary operator, but I'd recommend `if else` here for better readability.

Comment: @Object Manipulator yes of course, i just only show an another way to do  this

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `=` with `==` or you can do following with `isset()` and `empty()` functions.

Apart from that you can do following to remove duplication from your code.

```
$catid=$_GET['cat'];
$sel = "select * from listings where `stat`='Y'";

if(isset($_GET['cat']) && !empty($_GET['cat'])){
  $sel .= "and `category`='{$catid}'";
}

$sel .= " and order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();
```

Answer (score -3):

You should use like this

```
if(!$_GET['cat']) {
    $sel="select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();
} else {
    $sel="select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and `category`='{$catid}' order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Friends i made a mistake in my else query
$sel="select * from listings where `stat`='Y' and order by `sno` ".$pagination->getLimitSql();